# Need a package for tetrad formalism

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, differential-geometry

Does anyone know a package for tetrad formalism?
 want to convert a gravity action in terms of differential forms to tensorial expressions. A procedure known as tetrad formalism/Cartan formalism

Is there any package in this way in/for Mathematica?

Comment: I see that you asked the same question back in February, and unfortunately received no response ([Looking for a package for Cartan formalism in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/165425/27951)). There may not be one then.